# Win32_PerfFormattedData_RemoteAccess_RasPort WMI class on Windows XP

Tags: .net, windows, windows-xp, wmi

I'm getting 'Invalid class name' exceptions when trying to monitor changes to the `Win32_PerfFormattedData_RemoteAccess_RasPort` class on Windows XP. I'm using the code
[listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565734/capturing-vpn-usage-statistics).

Is this class supported on XP? The documentation claims it is, although it's supplied by a different provider. If not, what's a good alternative?

Answer (score 1):

[Win32_PerfFormattedData_RemoteAccess_RASPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394283.aspx) formatted data class is only found on server operating systems

Comment: And Vista. But there's definitely no XP alternative? iphlpapi.dll lies, and this class isn't available, there must be some reliable way to get usage stats on XP.

Comment: In Vista the Formatted Performance Data Provider is no longer available in the operating system, replaced with WMIPerfInst, I believe on XP that class is available but on Formatted Performance Data Provider(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390431.aspx)

Comment: How do you go about querying the different provider? Does the XP provider support the RemoteAccess performance counters, or some alternative?

Comment: yes it provides support for the performance counter in the link

Comment: So how do I query it with the classes available in the System.Management namespace in .NET?